# How to add anchor tag only to the p tag within a div and display p tag text in one line?

Tags: html, css

The `div` element has a background image. There's a `p` tag with the image description. However, I do not want the entire `div` element to be a hyperlink, only the text within the `p` tag.

current code:
html

```
<div id="p1" class="trp"><a href="#"><p>Jacob A.</p></a></div>
<div id="p2" class="trp"><p>In Jo Sung</p></div>
<div id="p3" class="trp"><p>Kim Min Ho</p></div>
```

css

```
.trp{
    height: 20px;
    width: 20px; 
    margin: 1%;   
    border: 1px solid black;
    -webkit-background-size: cover;
    -moz-background-size: cover;
    -o-background-size: cover;
    background-size: cover;

}

.trp p
{
    text-align:right;
    margin:0px 0px 0px 25px;
    display: inline-block;
    font-size:8pt;
    font-family:Lucida Sans;
    padding:2px;
}
```

Also, p tag text is showed in two lines instead of one line, although there's enough space.

[image]

Comment: p tag is showing text in one line. http://jsfiddle.net/1mm6x02b/

Comment: What's the vote down for? :T ? Well @Rasel I see the text is not in one line due to the above `.trp{}` css code of the div. That needs to be within the above width and height, because to maintain the aspect ratio of the background image of the div.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

p is a block level element. You cannot wrap a `paragraph` inside the `hyperlink`. This is HTML4 standard although it is ignored in HTML5.

**Correct code:**

```
<div id="p1" class="trp"><p><a href="#">Jacob A.</a></p></div>
<div id="p2" class="trp"><p>In Jo Sung</p></div>
<div id="p3" class="trp"><p>Kim Min Ho</p></div>
```

[**JSfiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/qtb03038/)

Answer (score 1):

As per your description, you may try the following:

```
<div id="p1" class="trp"><p><a href="#">Jacob A.</a></p></div>
```

Hope this may help. Best regards,

Comment: Try to increase the div (width: 20px;). Best regards,

Answer (score 1):

Hi i think in html 5 you can use `<a> <p>` inside a tag. But html 4.x and xhtml 1.x you can't.

Try this

```
<div id="p1" class="trp"><p><a href="#">Jacob A.</a></p></div>
```

And make the `<p> or <a>` `display:block`.